# Class 'Cassandra' not found

Tags: php, cassandra

i'm new to Ubuntu and Cassandra. I'm trying to install DataStax php driver according to : https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/blob/master/ext/README.md .
I've installed everything, and added extension=cassandra.so to apache2 php.ini file. But when i try to run some simple code like `$cluster = Cassandra::cluster()->build();` i get error : "Fatal error: Class 'Cassandra' not found in /var/www/html/test.php on line 3"

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below to you php file before you use the class

```
use Cassandra;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time, but maybe it can help to someone.

Adding `extension=cassandra.so` to apache2/php.ini should work, when you run on localhost. If you use some framework, such as cakePHP and you run server with `bin/cake server`, it will run on `http://localhost:8765/`. You also need to add `extension=cassandra.so` to cli/php.ini